# Clonezilla from MBR to GPT partition

Tags: linux, clonezilla

So i have a clonezilla image of a centos6.5 box.  It is 32GB in size.  I have restored this to many system, but they have all been small enough to still use MBR.  So when restoring i just used the -k2 option with advance mode to have the image fill up the whole disk.

I am now trying to do the same.  Restore this 32GB image to a 2TB GPT partition on a server.  the -k2 option does not work with GPT systems.  It was recommended to use the -k option, where clonezilla does not create the partitions.  I have tried to find examples of using this option without any luck.

I assume I need to use gparted or some other utility to create the partitions, but not sure what is needed past that.  Any help would be appreciated.